# FormControl becomes 'undefined' when using Prime NG's Dropdown with ngIf directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I have a dropdown component which eventually uses Prime NG's Dropdown Component with FormControl where I pass ParentFormGroup and FormControlName as input. Now I have a form which has a *ngIf directive attached to it. Whenever the page loads for the first time, my form gets populated with the value coming from the API. When I switch tab (which does not have that form) and come back again to the previous tab (which has the form), my formControl loses it's value and the control is undefined now. The control basically stores an object before but not it is undefined as I have switched tabs and my form was removed from the DOM and re-rendered again in the DOM.

myComponent.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isCohortDetailsTab" class="form-container p-20 height-100 overflow-y">
    <form [formGroup]="cohortDetailsForm">
      <app-dropdown
       [isFormField]="true"
       [dropdownItemsObj]="statuses"
       [parentFormGroup]="cohortDetailsForm"
       formCtrlName="statusFF"
       label="Status" 
       nameField="name"
       placeholder="Select Status"
       [isRequired]="true"
       errorText="Status is required"
      ></app-dropdown>
    </form>
</div>
```

myComponent.component.ts

```
const status: any = this.statuses.find((s: any) => s.id === this.eaCohortDetails.status_id);
this.cohortDetailsForm.get('statusFF')?.setValue(status);

// status is an object like { id: 1, name: 'Draft' }
```

dropdown.component.ts

```
<form *ngIf="isFormField" [formGroup]="parentFormGroup" class="dropdown-form-control">
  <label *ngIf="label">{{ label }}<span *ngIf="isRequired" class="required">*</span></label>
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="dropdownItemsArr"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
    [optionLabel]="nameField"
    [filter]="filter"
    [filterBy]="filterBy"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    (onChange)="onChange($event)"
    [title]="(selectedItem && selectedItem[nameField]) || placeholder"
    [showClear]="showClear"
    [formControlName]="formCtrlName"
    appendTo="body"
    [ngStyle]="{ 'cursor': disabled ? 'not-allowed' : '' }"
  >
  <ng-template pTemplate="selectedItem">
    <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2" *ngIf="selectedItem">
      <div>{{ selectedItem[nameField] }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
    <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2">
      <div>{{ item[nameField] }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  </p-dropdown>
  <app-error-message
      *ngIf="parentFormGroup.controls[formCtrlName].invalid && (parentFormGroup.controls[formCtrlName].dirty || parentFormGroup.controls[formCtrlName].touched)"
      [errorText]="errorText"
  >
  </app-error-message>
</form>
```

I tried using normal 'select' element from HTML and applied the formControl there and it worked. But it does not work with Prime NG's Dropdown.

Comment: Why are you using ngModel and formcontrol together, choose either, but not both :)